# Что это за числа в JavaScript: 1e10, 0x10, 0o10, 010, 0b10? Числовые литералы в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, числа, системы-счисления, литерал

Что это за числа: `0x10`, `0o10`, `010`, `0b10`?

- В какой системе счисления находится каждое число из приведённого списка?
- Чему равняется каждое число из приведённого списка?
- Почему та или иная буква используется для конкретного числа?
- Какие числа / буквы можно использовать при применении литерала?

И отдельно про `1e10`:

- Какому математическому выражению равняется `1e10`?
- Где и зачем используется такая запись?
- Что значит часть с `e10`?

---

О вопросе: "Числа, начинающиеся с нуля, в JavaScript".

Наши вопросы похожи, но мой вопрос про численные литералы в общем, а "оригинальный", про численные литералы являющиеся восьмеричными числами.

EDIT: Теперь я также добавил в запрашиваемую информацию литералы вида `1e10`, так что теперь, @Grundy не сможет отмечать мой вопрос как дубликат, [так ведь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wWW2.jpg)?

Comment: @Grundy прекратите пожалуйста. Это разные вопросы. Там про восьмеричную конкретику, тут - про более общее - форматы записи чисел.

Comment: @Grundy ты бы хоть объяснил своё поведение, а не тихушничал

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### 1. 0x10

Это шестнадцатеричный литерал, он равен 16 т.к. в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления 10 = 16. Латинская буква *x* используется т.к. в названии есть, собственно говоря, сам *x*: *he**x**adecimal*. [Подробнее в википедии](https://wikiless.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?lang=ru).

Можно использовать эти буквы и цифры: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d, e, f, A, B, C, D, E, F

### 2. 0o10/010

Эти два литерала (`0o10` и `010`) буквально равны друг другу т.к. оригинальные разработчики JavaScript решили так сделать. Эти литералы используются, чтобы обозначить, то что число в восьмеричной системы счисления, и равны 8. К слову, в JavaScript если попытаться к восьмеричному литералу написать 8 или 9, то тогда JavaScript выдаст ошибку (Пример: `0o48` -> `Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: numeric literal`). В `0o10` используется *o* т.к. на английском восьмеричный переводится как ***o**ctal*, а почему `010` сделали восьмеричной, мне не известно. [Подробнее в википедии](https://wikiless.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?lang=ru).

Можно использовать эти цифры: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

### 3. 0b10

А вот этот литерал используется в двоичной системе счисления и он равен 2. Используется *b* т.к. двоичный переводится как ***b**inary*. Если в таком числе использовать число которое не равняется 0 или 1, то тогда JavaScript выдаст ошибку. [Подробнее на википедии](https://wikiless.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?lang=ru)

Можно использовать эти цифры: 0, 1

#### В виде таблицы:

| Число | Система счисления | Равняется | Происхождение |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x10 | Шестнадцатеричная | 16 | He**x**adecimal |
| 0o10/010 | Восьмеричная | 8 | **O**ctal |
| 0b10 | Двоичная | 2 | **B**inary |

### 4. 1e10

Объясняя просто, 1e10 это математическое выражение которое в понятном нам виде выглядит так: `1 * (10 ^ 10)` (Или так, если вы хотите записать его в JS: `1 * (10 ** 10)`). Есть много видов записи такого литерала, вот некоторые из них (примеры с тысячей):

- `1e3` = `1000`
- `1e-3` = `0.001`

Часто такие литералы могут использоваться при минимизации (минификации) кода, т.к. позволяют сохранить пару байт.

В совокупности с вышесказанным, отвечаю на вопрос, `e10` значит *умножить на 10 возведя в 10 степень* (`1 * 10 ** 10`)

P.S. У таких литералов буква в начале также может записываться как заглавная, на работу это никак не влияет. (Примеры: `0X10`, `0O10`, `0B10`, `1E10`)

Comment: JS, конечно, странный язык, по логике `010` скорее уж двоичным должно было бы быть )

Comment: [Why are leading zeroes used to represent octal numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11483216), [Why are hexadecimal numbers prefixed with 0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2670639), [The curse of the leading zero](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140116-00/?p=2063)

Comment: @CrazyElf наверное 010  восьмеричное потому что 0 напоминает букву "o", а та, в свою очередь сокращение от "octo" (ну или на инглише подобное есть "octosyllabic"), что есть восемь/восьмисложный))

Comment: Если в числе первый ноль, то оно восьмеричное. Это общепринятая практика во многих языках. Кстати, на эти грабли многие наступают, когда конвертируют строки в числа. И при этом не указывают базис числа.

Comment: @newman `+'050' === 50`, `parseInt('050') === 50`, `Number('050') === 50`, попробуйте, вроде всё равняется 50. Можете показать пример или дать ссылку на его где можно воспроизвести проблему с переводом из строки в числа?

Comment: @ΝNL993, если число начинается с 0, то оно восьмеричное, такой трактовки придерживаются многие традиционные (начиная с 70-х годов) функции языка Си (естественно, если систему счисления надо угадать)

Comment: @ΝNL993, `вроде всё равняется 50`. Просто все уже наелись этого кактуса и сделали десятичную интерпретацию по умолчанию. Но раньше `parseInt` мог парсить строки, начинающиеся с нуля, как восьмеричные. См. [How do I work around JavaScript's parseInt octal behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/850341). Также про восьмеричный режим `parseInt` пока ещё можно прочесть [на русской версии MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: **про восьмеричную систему с нулём** : это была всего-лишь первая попытка основать бинарные числа. но история направила на более удобное 16-ричное исчисление. И 8-ричное с нулём впереди осталось как исторический след.